# Create .html file with php

Tags: php

i want to create a new .html file using php script as i new to php i don't understand to do it.
i founded a code but it m not working.

```
<?php
$filename = '/path/to/foo.html';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
  echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}?>
```

i want that when i load my page, an new .html file should be created to my path/ directory with some entries like  heading e.t.c in my html file

can anyone help me??

Comment: there must be `.php` extension and proper server set up.

Comment: you want the file to be created look the same as the one being loaded?

Comment: i want to create a new file with new file name

Comment: You clearly don't understand at all what you're doing, try reading some tutorials to at least grasp the necessary basics. Your question and your code are not related in any way.

Answer (score 8):

Best way to do it would be to write a small blank html file and save it somewhere; e.g. "template.html"

1) in PHP you can read it with

```
$newcontent = file_get_contents("template.html");
```

---

2) the open a new file with fopen, write new content, close the file. Done.

```
if (!file_exists('newname.html')) { $handle = fopen('path/to/new/file/newname.html','w+'); fwrite($handle,$newcontent); fclose($handle); }
```

Answer (score 3):

So, there are two parts of creation of new file:

- creation of content
- creation of own file

First you need to create content of that file. Here you can combine HTML and PHP code. For example

```
$TagCode = '<body>'.$Content.'</body>';
```

Or use nay template engine or code generator - and generated code save into any variable that you will use as content of created file.

And then you may create own file:

```
$File = fopen($Filename, $Mode);
```

where

```
`$Filename` means name of generated file (including its path)
`$Mode` means mode of file generation
```

Both arguments may be passed also directly (for example `fopen('file.ext', 'a')`)

Writing content of file follows

```
$Status = fwrite($File, $TagCode);
```

Then file is closed.

```
fclose($File);
```

And that is all - unless you would control if file was created correctly (then you use that function fwrite returns TRUE or FALSE - that you store in any variable - it is better than direct checking).

```
if($this -> Content === FALSE)
{
        ... /* error handling */
}
```

There are following modes of opening of files

- a - file content is not overwritten; only for adding of content; new content is placed below older content
- a+ - file content is not overwritten; for adding/reading of content; new content is placed below older content
- r - file content may be only read
- r+ - file content is not overwritten;, for adding/reading of content; new content is placed above older content
- w - file content is overwritten, only for adding of content
- w+ - file content is overwritten; for adding/reading of content

Instead functions `fopen`, `fwrite` and `fclose` may be used also [`file_puts_content`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php), but I like fopen, fwrite and fclose more.

Comment: Hello, sorry but i found nowhere what extension is supported for creating a file with fopen()....Can you advice me please ?

Comment: fopen() allows any file type, but it is very deprecated to try to create php and other similar files.

Comment: ok thanks a lot !! Do you consider html as "other similar files" ?

Comment: Files of server-side scripts. html is allowed. Some template machines pre-generate html files that are read later.

Answer (score 3):

```php
$text = "Text you want to add to your file";
file_put_contents('template.html', $text, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```