# (PHP) Creating HTML Files With Variable Content

Tags: php, html, fwrite

I was trying to have a form create a page to display information.  I was using `fwrite()` to create the page, but the way I set it up was very ugly and hard to manage, especially when I make the page more complex.  I was wondering if there was a different way (I can't imagine that there isn't).  Below is the code I have:

```
        $student_name = $_POST["student_name"];
        $text = "<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>" . $student_name . "'s Project</title></head><html><body><center><h1><u>" . $_POST["project_title"] . "</u></h1><i>By " . $student_name . "</i></center><br>" . $_POST["student_essay"] . "</body></html>";
        $student_page = fopen('./projects/' . $file_count - 1 . '.html', 'w');
        fwrite($student_page, $text);
```

Thanks!

Comment: a CMS would put that form data in a DB then use that create a file on-the-fly based of a template

Comment: What is a 'CMS'?  I'm not familiar.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system

Comment: The more you know...  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

Write a small blank html file and save it somewhere; e.g. "template.html"

1) in PHP you can read it with

```
$newcontent = file_get_contents("template.html");
```

2) Open a new file with fopen, write new content, close the file. Done.

```
if (!file_exists('newname.html')) { 
    $handle = fopen('path/to/new/file/newname.html', 'w+');
    fwrite($handle, $newcontent); 
    fclose($handle); 
}
```

However, what's the purpose of having a form create a new file everytime the form is submitted? Let me know what your objective is and I'll edit my answer accordingly.

You can see more answers and the original answer here: [Create .html file with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284182/create-html-file-with-php)

Comment: Right now, my goal is to create an archive for a variety of projects.  It will get a lot more complex soon and I want to keep this part as simple as possible.  This method does not help as much, since my goal isn't to append content, but thanks for the response!

Comment: What's the purpose of creating an archive for a variety of projects? is it that you need to keep logs? read data? create documents? If you can give me more specific details, I may be able to edit my answer to help you accordingly.