# How can I create a function/method that makes a new html file?

Tags: javascript, php, html

How could I make a method/function that would generate a new html file? I have tried certain methods that create a new window, but I would like a way to create a completely new html file at the push of a button. This file would be permanent and can be re-accessed later on.

Is it possible to do this? How?

Comment: `file_put_contents` springs to mind

Comment: Create it _where_? On the client? On the server?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284182/create-html-file-with-php) of any help?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I think that would work, is there a way to create a variable that holds a lot of html code that I could use in file_put_contents?